# Outlook 2016 Credentials in Credentials Manager

Tags: windows, outlook, office365, mapi

I'm writing a client application to access my mailbox using the Redemption/MAPI library. I used to be able to start a session by doing the following:

1.) Create a credentials MS.Outlook.15:{user's email} in windows credentials manager

2.) Create a profile

3.) Open a session using this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842103.aspx

However, once i enable "EnableADAL" flag in the registry. I'm unable to open a session successfully.

What I notice is that Outlook creates a credential named: MicrosoftOiffce16_Data:ADALWAM:{unique identifier of the user authenticated during ADAL token acquisition}

With that credential, i'm able to open a session successfully.

Anyone know what is stored in this credential? I've tried the ADAL refresh token and access token but they don't seem to be correct.

Comment: Try to see what Outlook does with the data returned by CredRead - the blob might be encrypted. You can use a utility like API Monitor from http://www.rohitab.com/ and trace CredRead / CredProtect / etc. credentials management functions.

Comment: I downloaded API Monitor, added filters for Advapi32.all which includes CredRead, added monitor for Outlook and Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin.exe. Only managed to see calls made to CredUnmarshalCredentialW for the email address and those calls returned false which is expected since they do not exist. I was expecting calls made for  MicrosoftOiffce16_Data:ADALWAM:{unique identifier of the user authenticated during ADAL token acquisition}.

Comment: So you do not see Outlook retrieving the credentials when it uses the account?